# Como criar um método que não espera terminar para retornar OK

Tags: c#, async, async-await

Eu preciso criar um método que retorne "OK" imediatamente, sem esperar que um método chamado por ele termine. como fazer isso?

```cs
    [WebMethod]
    public string ImportaDadosPosLeilaoValores(string fileName)
    {
        //a chamada abaixo irá demorar varios minutos, NÃO deve ser esperado o retorno dela
        ImportaDados(fileName);
        return "OK - Recebido";     // Resposta Imediata
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma como está no momento acredito que o mais simples seja apenas coloca-lo em uma task como da forma abaixo:

```
 [WebMethod] //WebServiceMethod 
    public string ImportaDadosPosLeilaoValores(string fileName) 
    { //a chamada abaixo irá demorar varios minutos, NÃO deve ser esperado o retorno //dela 
      Task.Run(()=>ImportaDados(fileName)); 
      return "OK - Recebido"; 
    // Resposta Imediata 
}
```

No entanto é possível trabalhar também com métodos assincronos através do modificador async, mas para isso teria que alterar não só esse método mas também o ImportaDados(), ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
[WebMethod] //WebServiceMethod 
        public async Task<string> ImportaDadosPosLeilaoValores(string fileName) 
        { //a chamada abaixo irá demorar varios minutos, NÃO deve ser esperado o 
          //retorno dela 
          ImportaDados(fileName); //esse método também teria o modificador async, e 
          //caso você chame o 'await' então ele esperaria para completar
          return "OK - Recebido"; 
        // Resposta Imediata 
    }
```